# My code executed only in console but not working in .js file

Tags: javascript

I have tried the following code to replace text character to the img tag inside div message.

However the code is working fine while i do in **console**. But when I try the same in my sticker.js  is not working. Can anyone tell me the reason?

The idea to make sticker box for chat app codded with Javascript and jQuery.

**User** 1 will send **:sticker1:** to public room and **replaced** with img src inside the #div

Now I'm trying document to call the script when div is showing but still not working.

```
$(document).ready(function()    is not working
```

And `$(function()` is not working either.

My chat app using template folder `/template/*.php` and web-cache folder to load the design. I am searching every where to find some solution but no luck.
I need help please

```js
$("#chat-sticker-container").ready(function stickers() {
var emoCodes = [
  ':sticker1:',
]; 
var $this = $("body");
 emoCodes.forEach(function(code) {
   var image = '<img src="https://sevendays.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/' + code.replace(/:/g, "") + '.jpg">';
   $this.find('p.chat-sticker').html(function(index, html) {    
  return html.replace(new RegExp(code, "g"), image);
   });

 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/sticker.js"></script>
 <dive id="chat-sticker-container">
 <p id="chat-sticker" class="chat-sticker">:sticker1:</p>

   
</dive>
```

Comment: Do you have a live environment where we can check out the entire page?

Comment: i will try to make it online as soon but i can confirm that..the div loaded after the script is loaded  because  the character :sticker1: exist in MSG line depends when the user send msg but i will make video today and i will show u

Comment: i will make video today and i will show u : https://streamable.com/vogjn

Comment: That is extremely helpful. I understand the problem. Are you the author of the chatroom app and if so can you add the code where you send the text message. Because you'll need to change the text **before** it is sent, not after.

Comment: thank you for reply : this is the input code ** <input contenteditable="true" id="textInputBox" class="chat-n1-textfield text-size14" value="" name="username"  maxlength="60" placeholder="Enter the text here">**

Comment: Add all of the code (inputs, buttons and everything on that screen) to your question, please.

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/vpsnemra1/h45w1xec/11/#save

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/vpsnemra1/h45w1xec/11/#save) I think you need to use the [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationObserverInit). This way you can check if an element, or the children of an element have been changed, added or removed.

I'm not able to figure out what the container is where the **chat divs** are added to the page, so I can only instruct you. But based on your fiddle I'm selecting the `chat-main-scroll-chatroom` div.

```
// List of emoCodes
var emoCodes = [
  ':sticker1:',
];

// Select chat container. Change if necessary.
var chatContainer = document.getElementById('chat-main-scroll-chatroom');

// Create a new observer.
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(entries) {

    // Check for emocodes whenever something has changed.
    emoCodes.forEach(function(code) {
        var image = '<img src="https://sevendays.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/' + code.replace(/:/g, "") + '.jpg">';
        $('p.chat-sticker').html(function(index, html) {    
            return html.replace(new RegExp(code, "g"), image);
        });
    });

});

// Check if children are changed
var options = { childList: true }

// Observer the chat container and check if itself or children are changing.
observer.observe(chatContainer, options);
```

So I really hope that this will help you out. In the best case scenario you would be able to filter the text that has been sent **before** the message is sent. If the API of your chat app provides such controls, then please use them.

Best of luck!

Comment: i did that but no luck <script type="text/javascript" src="js/stickers.js"></script> </body>

Comment: Is your `stickers.js` file found or does the console give a `404` error?

Comment: no..everything is loaded..i need some trick to wait this #chat-sticker-container loaded then load the function

Comment: Edited my answer. Try it out.

Comment: still no luck..must load the div before the script executed i need to keep the code holding till the #div loaded ..and idont no how to do that...this code working when i set setInterval()  but the message div keep loading and loading..

Comment: I've edited my answer and hope this will help you out. Otherwise I would suggest you look at the API of your chat app and see if they offer an option to manipulate the text before it is sent.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.*** that means he cant find selected div but when send the new code to console is working...i need somthing like runtime or setinterval to run the code in background without to reload the div of message bcs im trying setinterval  and is working but the div keep reload and reload but sticker is showing

Comment: Observe the **container** where the entire chat div is added **into**, not the div that you are trying to add.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JS is executing AFTER the html is in the DOM, this includes putting your script at the end of your body tag.

Comment: i did that but no luck <script type="text/javascript" src="js/stickers.js"></script>

</body>

Comment: Basically whatever method is writing that html in the dom needs to also call this code again

Comment: ya i need to call this code emoCodes.forEach(function(code) every time the #chat-sticker is showing

Answer (score 0):

Since the script is called before the html is defined its essentially working with nothing, putting the  after the html should fix the issues.

Comment: i did that but no luck <script type="text/javascript" src="js/stickers.js"></script> </body>